# JavaScript code to conditionally change link URL

Tags: javascript

I know this has been covered extensively as separate issues; I've tried copying verified answers, but I'm having trouble homologating Javascript conditional statements and a link URL change.

Essentially, what I need to do is detect mobile users and change a conference call URL to a tel link. I've been using  `if (screen.width <=699) {` as the condition and it works on redirects. Here's what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var call=document.getElementByID('phone');
if (screen.width <= 699) {
call.write('<a href="tel:!PHONENUMBER!">');
else
call.write('<a href="!URL!" target="blank">);
} 
//--!>
</script>
</head><body>
...
<a href="!URL!" id="phone">...</a>
```

I've also tried these with corresponding else statements to no avail:

- no var and `document.getElementByID('phone').write`
- `onclick = function() { window.location.href ='tel:!PHONENUMBER!};`.
- `call.src.replace('tel:!PHONENUMBER!');`
- `call.setAttribute("href",'tel:!PHONENUMBER!');`

I apologize if this is a super basic issue - I'm still learning Javascript. Thank you in advance.

Will

Answer (score 0):

You need to either wait for the page to finish loading before you execute your JavaScript or move your `script` block to the bottom of the HTML.

If you want to wait for the page to finish loading, then wrap your code in the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from @sepbot.

```
<body onload="mobileURL()">

<div id="phone"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function mobileURL() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerHTML="!LINKTEXT!";
    var myPhone = document.getElementById('phone');
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
        a.setAttribute('href', '!TELEPHONE!');
        myPhone.appendChild(a);
    } else {
        a.setAttribute('href', '!URL!');
        myPhone.appendChild(a);
    }
}
</script>
```